# Autocomplete Chronoform in Joomla 2.5

Tags: mootools, joomla-extensions, chronoforms

I'm creating a simple form using Chronoforms, but so far I haven't been able to solve a small problem.

I would love to load two or three fields in a search done by the autocomplete element, i currently have two autocompletes working, but i can't seem to be able to load the other values into the corresponding textboxes.

I'm including the link to the form

http://cfobb.ca/index.php?option=com_chronoforms&chronoform=nomination_form

and as it can be seen, the first two fields in the first tab are working autocompletes, but i would love to have them linked so when the user chooses in any of the two, the other automatically gets filled. That selection would also trigger another sql query (that i already have, nothing fancy) that would fill the School Name drop-down menu. Also there's this code in the help tab

```
 $form->data['_PLUGINS_']['autocomplete_processor']['result'];
```

but i don't really know how to use/handle it

Thanks

Comment: Which fields do you refer to in "user chooses in any of the two"

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear, the Number and Name fields of the first tab.